# EF6 Code First add CreatedDate & ModifiedDate column to existing database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to add CreatedDate and ModifiedDate column to existing database. What I need is everytime a row is added to the table, the `CreatedDate` and `ModifiedDate` will automatically set its value using `GETDATE()`, the difference between those is `ModifiedDate` will continue to be updated everytime a row is modified. I've been looking around and found mixed answer. Here's my code :

Entity

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    //I want to add CreatedDate and ModifiedDate here
}
```

Context :

```
public class TestContext: DbContext
{
    public TestContext()
        : base("TestContext")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //Student
        modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().HasKey(s => s.StudentID);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().Property(s => s.Name).IsRequired();
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled migration? If not, you can enable it in `Package Manager Console`. Open it and type:

`Enable-Migrations –EnableAutomaticMigrations`

Then, in the class `Student`:

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Come back to `Package Manager Console` and type: `Update-Database -Verbose`. Refresh your database and you will see them.

In the controller, you can access them via `TestContext`, like this:

```
public ActionResult GETDATE(string id)
{
   using (var db = new TestContext())
   {
      var createDate = db.Students.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id).CreateDate;
      //do something...
      return View();
   }
}
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: I think you only answered half of OP's question.